# MySQL joining three tables for posts, user info, and ratings

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I cannot imagine what MySQL query to use here. Here is the table:

```
users
-----
userid  name

posts
-----
postid  user_id message

ratings
-----
rateid  user_id post_id score
```

I want to be able to select the TOP 10 posts with the highest ratings based on the total number of all scores submitted by users.

The query I'm using is something like this but **it does not list items without ratings**:

```
SELECT *,IFNULL(SUM(score),0) score 
FROM posts 
LEFT JOIN ratings ON postid=post_id 
LEFT JOIN users ON userid=posts.user_id 
ORDER BY score DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

But I still want to be able to list those posts without ratings. Can you help me write the SQL query? Thanks!

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Comment: Did you try your query? What was the result?

Comment: I only get results WITH ratings. Those items in posts that do not have corresponding ratings do not get listed.

Comment: try with `... right join ratings ON postid=post_id ...`

Comment: since you have an outer join, it should list them... Try also replacing IFNULL(SUM(score),0) by SUM(IFNULL(score,0))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT post_id,coalesce(score, 0) score 
FROM posts 
LEFT JOIN ratings ON postid=post_id 
LEFT JOIN users ON userid=posts.user_id 
GROUP BY post_id
ORDER BY coalesce(score, 0) DESC 
LIMIT 10
```